# Dynamically upload attachments with trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I have an integration in place for Infor LN ERP to Salesforce (Inforce).

Part of the integration covers the synchronisation of invoices for which there is a invoice object: InForceEW__invoice__c

When an invoice is created or modified in LN a BOD is fired to Salesforce to Upsert a record. LN also creates an ~20KB PDF of the invoice on a local drive (within a couple of seconds). *From experience the PDF is created well before the BODs are processed*.

I have a trigger in place for handling of the invoice BOD, however I was wondering if it would be possible to add something that would automatically upload the pdf of the invoice to Salesforce and then add a link to pdf on the invoice record.

The name of the invoice record is logically linked to the name of the PDF document.

It will probably be a big step up for me to add this functionality and some guidance, especially on the feasibility would be extremely useful.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: By "upload," do you mean that Salesforce should find the invoice in Infor LN ERP? If so, this may be a question to ask in a product-specific forum, as documentation for the outside system would be needed so that one could generate some sort of GET callout from Salesforce to retrieve the PDF.

Comment: Hi David, I was hoping to upload the PDF from the local folder into salesforce as an attachment (automatically). That way it could be accessed in SF1 (I believe).  I created a dynamic hyperlink to the PDF on the local drive on the invoice object, which works great on the desktop version, but this doesn't work for the guys out running SF1.

Comment: The question is of how to initiate the upload. Triggering in Salesforce cannot initiate an upload - only a query. If the local system makes the PDF, then the local system must trigger the code to upload the file. Salesforce doesn't "know" about the PDF so cannot pull it in.

Comment: Ok, I was hoping that when an invoice record was created a trigger could then initiate an upload of a file in a set folder with a name based upon the record name.

Comment: Yes, and that trigger has to fire on the *local* platform and cannot fire in Salesforce - which is why this is a better question for the vendor of the local system.

Comment: That's a shame I thought the trigger on the Invoice record being created in Salesforce would have worked.  Maybe I'll look at using the dataloader and doing a regular upload that way. Thanks for the advice.